# Convert sentence to array of words without explode or split method in php

Tags: php

I am trying to convert string into array without using explode or split method.

for example for:

```
$input = "I am a developer";
```

I want to get:

```
$output = ['I','am','a','developer']
```

I tried

```
<?php
$a = "I am a developer";
$currentindex = 0;
$output=array();

for($i=0;$i<strlen($a);$i++){
    if($a[$i] == " "){
        $temp = substr($a,$currentindex,$i);
        $output[]=$temp;
        $currentindex = $i+1;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that when you call `substr()` the third parameter is the length of the string you want and not the position, so just subtract the `$currentindex` from it...

```
$temp = substr($a, $currentindex, $i - $currentindex);
```

You are also missing the last part, so after the loop add (you can just take the rest of the string in this case)...

```
$output[] = substr($a, $currentindex);
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot @nigel. These type of questions are asked a lot in interviews

Comment: Know your language and use str_word_count(). See my answer below.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, as it looks more like a *why doesn't this code work* type question, understanding the problem is sometimes more important than just replacing it with something else - most people would just say use `explode()`

Comment: Would be a more appropriate task for C++ users. PHP is typeless dirty - almost. Question looks more like please help me doing my homework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative version without any string functions. It has a `$currentWord` string instead and keep building it until it reaches a space, then resets it to an empty string and so on:

```
$text = 'I am a developer';

$words = [];
$currentWord = '';
for ($pos = 0, $length = strlen($text); $pos < $length; $pos++) {
  if ($text[$pos] === ' ') {
    $words[] = $currentWord;
    $currentWord = '';
  }
  else {
    $currentWord .= $text[$pos];
  }
}
$words[] = $currentWord;

print_r($words);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/F8VIi**

Note: obviously it doesn't handle multiple spaces and other specific cases, I willingly kept it basic.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a rather arbitrary requirement to not use `explode()` or `split()`, but since those are the only two functions you explicitly banned, there are other options that don't require manual iteration:

```
$array = preg_split('/\s+/', $input)
```

Or:

```
$array = str_getcsv($input, ' ');
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => I
    [1] => am
    [2] => a
    [3] => developer
)
```

Comment: It's impossible to tell for sure from the question, but my guess is this is for an exercise and you have to do it manually/the old-fashioned way.

Comment: Heh yes I imagine that might be the case but I would posit that my solutions fully meet the stated requirements. :)

Answer (score 0):

PHP does have a [function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php) exactly for that.

```php
$input = "I am a developer";
$words = str_word_count($input, 1);
```

Will output

> array(4) {
>    [0] =>
>    string(1) "I"
>    [1] =>
>    string(2) "am"
>    [2] =>
>    string(1) "a"
>    [3] =>
>    string(9) "developer"
>   }